# deprecated Time().getHours() Vs Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); VsLocalDateTime.now().getHour();

Tags: java, android, deprecated

I'm just confused of what should i use out of this three ways to get the current hour of the device, I found that the deprecated Time().getHours() can run in almost all my devices I'm testing with but the new calendar and LocalDate time have some APIs restrictions which make them not working with all devices.. 
the question is should i use the deprecated one since it's targeted to all the devices ? or it's better to use one of the newest and do API check if it's lower then use the deprecated? and what's the best way ? 
Thanks.

Comment: the best way is to implement the latest library on all devices but you can also implement an API check and implement both  new and old versions.

Comment: is there latest library that works in all devices ?  I see latest only starts with API lvl 26 or 24..

Comment: I am sure the latest one will also have support for older versions. If it's not there you can always use both libraries with a proper API check :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clear your confusion, You have to check on these thing. First of all you have to see when the deprecated API was introduced. I mean You need to see In which Android version that particular API was include.

Then Check for the replacement API. For example API ABC is deprecated. and its replacement is API XYZ .... So in this way let say API ABC was introduced in API level 1, and API XYZ is introduced API level 17 and later, then it is appropriate to make an API check if your device api is minimum of 17 Use API ABC else API XYZ .

In your case Calendar API is introduces in api level 24, and Time api is deprecated, Make a check on API if your device has lower api then 24 use Time API else use Calendar API for the devices having API level 24 or later.

Comment: Okay perfect, i will do the logic but i thought i will get something that can work normally in all devices  and not deprecated since it's not that big thing to take the time in the same way from all devices.

Comment: I do not see taking time using calendar will create any problem. That is why I am saying You have to improve some logic since I have not seen what you have done to get the time.

Comment: Calendar requires min API level 24 my app is 19 !

Comment: @Waged share me Calendar API link

Comment: ok, Got it, thanks , Omit my last comment in answer, Just gave you the key, and do that as I said. Just make a check for lower version then api level 24 and get time

Comment: edited my answer. Please go ahead and read again. Hope this will help you

Comment: okay, perfect but is that the best practice for it ? do they provide something much more robust and supporting all android devices ? this the question ? any ideas ?

Comment: No, Whereas they release some api that have back portability I mean support for earlier version, In this case that is most like thing to use. But in those API those they declared as deprecated, then it is best practice to use the newer API for newer versions. now You are clear?